# Error in Google Play Services: read failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, ioexception, google-cloud-messaging

Here is the LogCat error I am getting:

```
android java.io.IOException: read failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:435)
```

The error is given in the following code, where I am trying to register a device using AsyncTask:

```
private void registerInBackground(){
    mRegisterIdTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;
                /* TODO : Send regId to backend to store in database so backend can send...
                   TODO : ...push notification request to GooglePlayMessaging
                 */
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();
                storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                msg = "Error : " + e.getMessage();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i("Google Play", "Status : Finished ");
            mRegisterIdTask = null;
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Well now I'm getting this and I haven't changed anything.

```
05-15 17:33:35.253  16020-16271/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.panicsystems.kyuubi.legalpanicpartner, PID: 16020
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1603)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1580)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:494)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.zzs(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
        at com.kyuubi.MainActivity$2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:171)
        at com.kyuubi.MainActivity$2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:161)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: are you using Cyanogen ?

Comment: Share your code that uses Google Play Services.

Comment: Not using Cyanogen mod

Comment: @reemul Please post full logcat and code, we can't help you if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually read the logs it is pretty clear what's the problem.

**You are missing a required permission needed to use GCM.**

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service
>   Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER
>   pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission
>   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

Inside AndroidManifest.xml add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

And make sure you have a GCM receiver registered

```
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <!-- support pre-4.4 KitKat devices -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.company.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and your service:

```
 <service
       android:name="com.company.app.service.GcmRegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" >
 </service>
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I resolved this but I do believe that was the issue.